# NodeJS not detected over remote Powershell

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, npm

Installed nodejs and npm package on windows. No problems while running commands locally, but on SSH powershell (remoting in), it says "node" command not found. Similar results from npm command too.

Comment: Is the Node.js installation on the target machine a _user-level_ one, and are you perhaps using a different user account for the remote access?

Comment: I'm using same account for access and node js is installed for all users.

Comment: Compare the value of `$env:PATH -split [IO.Path]::PathSeparator` in the local vs. the remote case.